# AngularJS array separate by comma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following JSON which will be set to $scope.episodes;

```
"the_numbers": [{
    "episodeID": 16503,
    "episodeNumber": 183
},
{
    "episodeID": 16504,
    "episodeNumber": 184
}]
```

From this JSON I want to create a filter in angularjs to get the following output from $scope.episodes: `183, 184`.

What has to be done to achieve that?

Comment: you can try using underscorejs(_) 's pluck method.

Comment: @VikashVerma and how do you know that he is having underscore?

Comment: @tanmay : I m suggesting him to use underscore inside angular controller.

Comment: `$scope.episodes = theNumbers.map(function(x){ return x.episodeNumber});`

Comment: @VikashVerma this is fairly simple use-case and can be achieved without using underscore as well

Comment: @Elmer Dantas, if there is no better solution, than your solution is absolutely working!! :)

Comment: I don't know the whole scenario of what you're doing...but if you just want an array with specific fields from an array of objects, that's all what you need. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.episodes = {
    "the_numbers": [{
        "episodeID": 16503,
        "episodeNumber": 183
    },
    {
        "episodeID": 16504,
        "episodeNumber": 184
    }]
};

return $scope.episodes.the_numbers.map(function(item){
    return item.episodeNumber;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('plucker', function() {
  return function(input, key) {
    input = input || [];
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      values.push(input[i][key]);
    }
    return values.join(', ');
  };
});
```

Then in your template you can use:

```
{{ episodes | plucker:'episodeNumber' }}
```

Comment: Nice method, but it looks more complicated then the map function provided by Pleshi Bloy :)

Comment: Thanks!  You indicated you wanted a filter.  I assumed you wanted an angular filter.   In any case, this one is reusable.